# how i can using mx_controller variables in my own library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, controller, hmvc

I am working on a project using HMVC codeigniter. i have my own library for layouts and my base controller named MY_Controller with this code:

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller{
    public $layout='layout_name';
    public $theme='name';
    ...
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        ...
        }
}
```

my problem is:
when i use `$this->CI=& get_instance();` in the library, the properties of my controller like `$theme` are unavailable. for example can not use `$this->CI->theme;` but in the controllers no problem exist and i can use `$this->theme;` anywhere. how can i make an instance contain my base controller variables in the library?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. according to the [CI documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html), i use second parameter of loading library and send my specified variables to library via array. in the mx_controller:

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller{

    private $layout='default';
    private $theme='white';
    private $param=array();

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->param=array('layout'=>$this->layout,'theme'=>$this->theme);
        $this->load->library('lib',$this->param);
    }
}
```